# How to converge multiple R files into one single file

Tags: r

**Situation**

I wrote an R program which I split up into multiple R-files for the sake of keeping a good code structure.
There is a Main.R file which references all the other R-files with the 'source()' command, like this:

```
source(paste(getwd(), dirname1, 'otherfile1.R', sep="/"))
source(paste(getwd(), dirname3, 'otherfile2.R', sep="/"))
...
```

As you can see, the working directory needs to be set correctly in advance, otherwise, this could go wrong.
Now, if I want to share this R program with someone else, I have to pass all the R files and folders in relative order of each other for things to work. Hence my next question.

**Question**

Is there a way to replace all the 'source' commands with the actual R script code which it refers to? That way, I have a SINGLE R script file, which I can simply pass along without having to worry about setting the working directory.

I'm not looking for a solution which is an 'R package' (which by the way is one single directory, so I would lose my own directory structure). I simply wondering if there is an easy way to combine these self-referencing R files into one single file.

Thanks,

Comment: Just as a side note, in case you are using RStudio, you can also consider using a "Project"-structure for future work. This is easier to share when you have relative R files, data etc.

Comment: Why or how is just zipping them together not an option? Saves folder structure, so once unpacked everything will work.

Comment: I know zipping is surely an option, and everything will still work. But making sure the working directory is correctly set, is one of the reasons this could go wrong. Anyhow, I'm just curious if replacing 'source' with the actual scripts is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think you could use something like scaning all the files and then writting them again in the same new one. This can be done using `readLines` and `sink`:

```
sink("mynewRfile.R")

for(i in Nfiles){
    current_file = readLines(filedir[i])
    cat("\n\n#### Current file:",filedir[i],"\n\n")
    cat(current_file, sep ="\n")
}

sink()
```

Here I have supposed all your file directories are in a vector `filedir` with length `Nfiles`, I guess you can adapt that

Comment: I'll guess this is the closest one can get. I'll accept the answer.

Comment: An other things: if you don't want to write the `filedir`vector by hand, you can use `list.files` especially with option `pattern =".R"`

Comment: I found a similar answer on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GzCtx5XMNE ,